# all product identifiers are invalid in my ' in app purchase' application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store, in-app-purchase

app id: `com.riseuplabs.newapn`

product id: `com.riseuplabs.newapn.01` and `com.riseuplabs.newapn.02`

The bundle Id is correct, provisioning profile is correct, product Ids (`com.vendor.appname.itemname`) are relative to the bundle Id (`com.vendor.appname`).
In creating the purchase items with unchecked "cleared for sale".

I have request the product by following code:

```
SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: 
                             [NSSet setWithObjects: @"com.riseuplabs.newapn.01",         
                                                @"com.riseuplabs.newapn.02",
                                                @"01", @"02", nil]];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];



- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
  NSLog(@"didRecieveResponse");

  NSLog(@"%@",response.products);
  NSLog(@"%@",response.invalidProductIdentifiers);
}
```

but in response: I got all my product id are in invalidProductIdentifiers array.

Answer (score 0):

This confused me for a while too.

You need to enable the "Cleared for Sale" setting. When you've done this it will be available from the sandbox store -- you created an "In App Purchase Test User" in iTunes Connect, right?

The other confusing bit is that you have to log out of iTunes on your handset before starting your application. You do this by going into the App Store program, clicking your account (the bottom button on the Featured tab), and then pressing the Sign Out button.

Note that this only works on the handset and not in the iPhone simulator.

After you do this you will still need approve it before it goes live on the store for real.

Comment: I have checked "clear for sale", also create test user and also i have run my app in my device
but no success yet...

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?  Last week my test app worked fine, but suddenly now all my app identifiers are invalid... Cleared for sale and test user stuff is all fine, and as before.

Answer (score 0):

In App sales is the most infuriating feature I have tried to implement.  I have the exact same problems as above.  I can see my products in the simulator but I have to remove the appid and leave only the product id

from com.company.app.feature1 to feature1 in the simulator but nothing works in the device.

**UPDATE:**

Well, I redid everything and made sure to make my product IDs com.company.app.feature1 instead of just feature1 and then, here's the biggy... REMOVED that jailbreak. That got me real good and the moment I restored and ran the app from xcode to my device, it all worked as it should.

Even if youre not JB, a simple restore from backup may not be a bad idea if youre willing to go last resort.